# Transformation of Quadratic Surface with a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, surfaces, quadratic-forms

I am not very familiar with quadratic surfaces, but spontaneously I start to think about it. I thought that surfaces like 
$$
2x^2+2xy+4yz+z^2=1
$$
can be written into the form $au^2+bv^2+cw^2=1$ on an orthonormal basis. To do this, I tried to write the surface into the form
$$
(2x+y)^2-9y^2+(z-2y)^2=2,
$$
but when I attempt to perform transform $u=2x+y, u=y$ and so on, I find that although the desired form is achieved, the resulting new basis is not orthonormal (because the matrix is not symmetric). I try to randomly guess other matrices to use, but that doesn't help.

My question is: **is it at all possible** to express the surface (actually a hyperboloid) in an orthonormal basis in the form $au^2+bv^2+cw^2=1$? If so, how can I find the desired real and symmetric matrix?

Comment: if you demand an orthonormal change, you will get eigenvalues $3, \sqrt 3, -\sqrt 3.$

Comment: Yes, write $x=cx'-sy', y = sx'+cy'$. Substitute and equate the coefficient of $x'y'$ to zero. The resulting equation and $s^2+c^2=1$ gives you a system of equations from which you can solve for $c$ and $s$. The resulting change of coordinates from $x,y,z$ to $x',y',z$ is orthogonal, a [Givens' roration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not demand orthonormal change,

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

leads to
$$ 2 \left(x + \frac{y}{2} \right)^2 - \frac{1}{2} ( y - 4 z)^2 + 9 z^2  $$

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 2 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 4 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$